# How does this read a 'zero' when comparing two arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, compare

```
int num4[10] = {3,4,8,9};
int num2[10] = {3,8,6,8};

compare2 = memcmp(num4, num2, 4);
```

Why is the value of compare2 zero even though the arrays are not equal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third argument to `memcmp` is the number of bytes, not the number of elements.

You meant:

```
memcmp(num4, num2, 4 * sizeof num4[0]);
```

Your existing code only compares the first four bytes. If your system has 4-byte ints (which is common) then you only compared the first int.

I used `sizeof num4[0]` instead of `sizeof(int)` so that the code still works even if you later change `num4` and `num2` to be a different type of array.